# after Firebase init package.json not found during deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I tried this twice with two different projects and am getting the same error. After I installed **node.js** and did **npm install -g firebase-tools**. I first cd to the project directory in the CLI. I then do a **firebase init** and it runs fine. When I do a **firebase deploy**, I get this same error each time.
I am being told that a file is missing (package.json). I can see this file in the functions folder and in the main directory (entire_painting).

```
Hosting URL: https://entire-painting-ei.firebaseapp.com

c:\xampp\htdocs\Entire_Painting>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'entire-painting-ei'...

i  deploying functions

Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint

npm ERR! path c:\xampp\htdocs\Entire_Painting\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\xampp\htdocs\Entire_
Painting\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-01T01_39_39_
398Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294
963238

c:\xampp\htdocs\Entire_Painting>
```

Comment: Please don't show images of code and errors in questions.  It's better to copy the text into a question directly so that it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to list exactly the steps you took to get to this point, before `firebase init`.

Comment: Ok, sorry Doug. I've changed the error to text rather than image. So before the init,  I installed node.js, ran npm install -g firebase-tools, I CD'd to my directory and did the firebase init. All seamed fine until I did the deploy. I received this error when I did a general deploy so I did a deploy --only on the database, hosting and functions. I only got this error on the functions.

Comment: Did you use `firebase init functions`?

Comment: So, is `package.json` actually missing?

Comment: @arnold...Yes I did, it ran fine with no errors.

Comment: @doug - yes I looked in the $RESOURCE_DIR and the file is not there.

Comment: $RESOURCE_DIR is isolated to the firebase CLI.  You couldn't have used that yourself.  The issue whether or not that file exists in your `functions` directory.

Comment: @doug - you got me thinking. I just did a search for the package.json file in the entire_painting directory and it appears there. Do you think I should move it to the $RESOURCE_DIR or would this cause problems?

Comment: Yes it's in my functions directory

Comment: I strongly suggest you go through the steps of creating a new project and documenting that here (by editing your question) so we can see exactly what happened prior to the init.  I've deployed hundreds of times across many projects, and I've never seen this before.

Comment: I found a work around. I don't think it's a best solution though. I went into the package.json file in my root directory and changed $RESOURCE_DIR to %RESOURCE_DIR%. It seemed to solve the issue.